# C# deserialize special data

Tags: c#

I create a function in c# to query ikea tradfri, here the result :

```
"<//15001/65536>;ct=0;obs,<//15001/65537>;ct=0;obs,<//15004/136834>;ct=0;obs,<//15005/136834/217609>;ct=0;obs,<//15005/136834/218326>;ct=0;obs,<//15005/136834/224384>;ct=0;obs,<//15005/136834>;ct=0;obs,<//15001>;ct=0;obs,<//15001/reset>;ct=0,<//status>;ct=0;obs,<//15005>;ct=0;obs,<//15004>;ct=0;obs,<//15004/add>;ct=0,<//15004/remove>;ct=0,<//15006>;ct=0;obs,<//15011/15012>;ct=0;obs,<//15011/9034>;ct=0,<//15011/9030>;ct=0,<//15011/9031>;ct=0,<//15011/9063>;ct=0,<//15011/9033>;ct=0,<//15010>;ct=0;obs"
```

Now I need to isolate everything that start with //15001/

I try JavaScript serializer or Newsoft but I don't achieve to get everything in order to go through.

Do you have tips to deserialize this kind of data in c# ?

thank for your help !

Comment: what do you mean by using the word "deserialize"' ?

Comment: It looks to me like you should split on comma (`','`). Each segment then has a semi-colon as a delimiter, and consists of a path of some kind in angle brackets, "ct=0" (perhaps a count, which happens always to be zero in the results you showed us?), and optionally "obs". I'd want to throw a lot of queries at their webservice to see what else shows up. But it looks like a very simple non-hierarchical format so far. You're a programmer; write some code. And look for some documentation.

Comment: Why would a JSON deserializer be of use here when this isn't valid JSON?

Comment: @Amy Well, maybe OP doesn't know much about serialization formats. I think that's a reasonable interpretation of this question. In fact, there's no other interpretation that even begins to make sense. Of course, if OP *hadn't* mentioned JSON, you'd (rightly) be all "what did you try?"

Comment: Yeah maybe "deserializer" isn't well choose. Basically I want to be able to loop through the result to output what I need.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like you are trying to query a CoAP service/endpoint. Awesome stuff, fortunately theres already open source implementations of the CoAP standard, including resource parsing, URI resolution, among others.

Here's a [C# library](https://github.com/smeshlink/CoAP.NET) that's linked from the [CoAP Wiki page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Constrained_Application_Protocol)

Comment: Thank ! I found the code : IEnumerable links = LinkFormat.Parse(response.PayloadString);